# confusion in using select command in postgresql with timestamp column

Tags: postgresql

I have table which has structure like this.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL
    )
```

I have more than 1000 records in this table.
This is my first query.

**1 query**

```
select id,created_at from users where id in  (1051,1052)
```

[image]

This returns two rows which is correct as as expected. However when I use

**2nd Query**

```
select id,created_at from users where  created_at = '2020-06-28'
```

or

```
select id,created_at from users where  created_at = date '2020-06-28'
```

It returns nothing, this is not expected result as it should return two rows against it.

[image]

Similarly if I use this

**3rd Query**

```
select id, created_at from users where created_at between date '2020-06-28' and date '2020-06-28'
```

It returns nothing however I think this should also return two rows.

[image]

While this

**4th Query**

```
select id, created_at from users where created_at between date '2020-06-28' and date '2020-06-29'
```

returns two rows.
[image]

Show timezone  returns correct timezong in which currently i am

[image]

I did`t understand this, why the results are different in 2nd, 3rd and 4th query. How can i get same result as of query 1 using 3rd query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One single reason for all your queries is that you are comparing `timestamp` with `date`

in **Query 2**

You are comparing `2020-06-28 13:02:53 = 2020-06-28 00:00:00` which will not match so returning no records.

in **Query 3**

You are using `between` i.e. `2020-06-28 13:02:53 between 2020-06-28 00:00:00 and 2020-06-28 00:00:00` which will not match so returning no records.

in **Query 4**

You are using `between` i.e. `2020-06-28 13:02:53 between 2020-06-28 00:00:00 and 2020-06-29 00:00:00`. Here both records are falling in those timestamps and you are getting the records

So you have to compare date values. As right operand is a `date` type value, you have to convert the left operand to `date`. try this

for **2nd Query**

```
select id,created_at from users where  date(created_at) = '2020-06-28'
```

for **3rd Query**

```
select id, created_at from users where date(created_at) between date '2020-06-28' and date '2020-06-28'
```

You should opt 3rd method if you want to compare a date range. For one day only you should use 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

Because what you are doing is:

```
test(5432)=# select '2020-06-28'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 06/28/2020 00:00:00
```

You are selecting for created_at that is exactly at midnight and there is none.  The same thing when you do:

`select id, created_at from users where created_at between date '2020-06-28' and date '2020-06-28'`

You already corrected the mistake in your 3rd query in the 4th query:

`select id, created_at from users where created_at between date '2020-06-28' and date '2020-06-29'`

where you span the time from midnight of 06/28/2020 to midnight 06/29/2020

An alternate solution is:

```
create table dt_test(id integer, ts_fld timestamp);
insert into dt_test values (1, '07/04/2020 8:00'), (2, '07/05/2020 1:00'), (3, '07/05/2020 8:15');
select * from dt_test ;
 id |       ts_fld        
----+---------------------
  1 | 07/04/2020 08:00:00
  2 | 07/05/2020 01:00:00
  3 | 07/05/2020 08:15:00

select * from dt_test where date_trunc('days', ts_fld) = '07/05/2020'::date;
 id |       ts_fld        
----+---------------------
  2 | 07/05/2020 01:00:00
  3 | 07/05/2020 08:15:00
```

In your case:

```
select id, created_at from users where date_trunc('days', created_at) = '2020-06-28'::date;
```

Comment: what about query2. Why cant i get results with this. I think it should return two rows.

Comment: No you won't as I explained in the first example. ```created_at = '2020-06-28'``` becomes ```created_at = '06/28/2020 00:00:00'``` and there no such values to match.